# Controller is connecting to other PlayStation 3 consoles, but not mine

Tags: ps3, controllers

My controller was working fine. I was playing a game, and then it suddenly disconnected, and now it only connects with a cable. Without the cable, when I press the PS button, it starts blinking and then just stops.

I tried a friends controller that worked just fine on his console, but the same problem occurred on mine.

Why would controllers be unable to connect without the cable?

Comment: When you mean the controller 'stops', do you mean stops blinking?

Comment: You tried a friends controller on his console? How would that help test anything? Or am I reading that wrong? Have you tried any other controllers on **your** console?

Answer (score 2):

The PlayStation 3 uses a direct cable for data, if connected.

Without the cable, it is using Bluetooth to transmit the data. If your PlayStation can not connect to working controllers, there appears to be a problem with Bluetooth. This could be a fault with the console, or a software issue.

Your best bet is to contact [Sony technical support](https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/select-system.pl?DIRECTOR=CONTACT) in regards to the issue. If you are still under warranty, you could also return to the store you purchased the console from.